How to fetch and display data from the corresponding column in database in phpMyAdmin
I have been trying to fetch and display the corresponging first name, last name, email, and username (once logged in) to a HTML file and I cant seem to get the information to display. Please help.
//SAA_Register_Connect.php
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register(firstName, lastName, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $username, $password);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        if ($execval === FALSE) {
            echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
        } else {
            echo "Registration successfully...";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>

//SAA_Login_Connect.php
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Prepare SQL statement to retrieve user data
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($stmt_result->num_rows > 0) {
        $data = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc();
        if($data['password'] === $password){
            echo json_encode(array("message" => "Login Successfully",));
        }
        else{
            echo json_encode(array("error" => "Invalid Email or Password"));
        }
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "Invalid Email or Password"));
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
?>

I tried creating a session in "SAA_Login_Connect.php" to get the fields I wanted and then display them in the html file but I would only receive a login error.

Add the errors you are getting

(1) You should not save plain password in DB (2) For the data you want, they should be stored in $data['xxxx'] upon successful running of SAA_Login_Connect.php (e.g. $data['firstName'] is the firstname ) (3) You have said twice : HTML file -- please note that under normal circumstances a html file cannot be used to execute PHP command(s)

We don't seem to have a [mre] of the issue, and there's no debugging or error description provided. So we can only guess, really. Please [edit] your question with better details. Remember we can't see your screen. The [ask] guide is useful too. Thanks

You have 2 error situations and both send exactly the same error message. So how do you know which issue you are having.

Also maybe a small point but: phpMyAdmin is not a database its a tool written in PHP to help beginners get around MySQL or mariaDB The later 2 are databases.

@RiggsFolly It's good security practice not to reveal whether it was the email/username or the password (or both) which was entered incorrectly. But I agree, for debugging purposes it's not very helpful. The OP could, of course, temporarily add some extra information to one of the messages in order to help themselves. Or use a debugger.
